# Apps Script CSS Fonts

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

I am trying to customize some fonts in Google Apps Script, yet keep getting the same answer: Syntax error. (line 3, file "CSS"). This is my CSS.gs tab:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
var css={};
css.div = { fontFamily:"Courier New"};
```

Where have I gone wrong???

Comment: I don't think you can include HTML or CSS in a .gs file -- check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript

Comment: No, I can...Ive seen others with it

Comment: certainly not by putting an html tag inside javascript. must be in the html side

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? Google Developers has not been helpful for css.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side Google Apps Script doesn't do anything directly to style HTML output on the client side.

Option 1: Include `<style>` tags in your HTML file (not in GS).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<style>
div { 
  fontFamily:"Courier New";
}
</style>

...
```

Option 2: Inline style, again in your HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<div style='fontFamily:"Courier New";'>
...
</div>
```

Option 3: Use a separate HTML file for your css, which you import into your HTML. This is demonstrated in the Best Practices documentation, under [Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript). Since the css isn't being `link`ed as a stylesheet, but instead is imported HTML, you need to include the `<style>` tags.